# Django; Why empty_label is not shown in ModelChoiceField?

Tags: python, django

I have the next code:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = ModelChoiceField(
        label='Delegación', required=False,
        empty_label='---- Select ----',
        queryset=Model.objects.all()
    )
```

This does not show the empty_label.   I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label)

> Note that if a ModelChoiceField is required and has a default initial
>   value, no empty choice is created (regardless of the value of
>   empty_label).

By default every field is required. So how do you use the form? Do you provide some initial value? Try to set `required=False` to see if this is the reason for not showing the empty_label.

Comment: Hello @Todor I have established. required=False

Comment: The form has no initial values. @Todor